# How to create Friendship Graph in NEO4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am new to neo4j and trying some stuff. I have two csv files: one with people, and one with friendship relationships.

I am trying to create a graph of friendship relationships between people, and I also want to do updates like: renaming people's names, changing the friendship relationships, and lastly I also want to run queries like "who are friends with Allen".

- `people.csv` looks like this:

  ```
  id, name
  1, Allen
  2, John
  ```
- `friendship.csv` looks like this:

  ```
  TO, FROM
  Allen, John
  ```

I have loaded these csv using code below:

```
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///friendship.csv' AS line WITH line LIMIT 100 RETURN line
```

I have found different code for creating relationships, but I am confused about them.

**Can anyone tell me how to create simple relationship of friendship mapping from the csv? and thereafter how to add more relationships using neo4j?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you read the tutorial here: https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/ ?

A simple way to get started is, first create nodes from people.csv (assuming they're unique values, you can use a CREATE instead of a MERGE), for example

```
CREATE (:Person {id:line.id, name:line.name})
```

Set up indexes as required, in your case, on the persons name.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name);
```

Then create relationships by running a LOAD CSV on friendship.csv and MATCHing the nodes previously created

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV FROM 'file:///friendship.csv' AS line WITH line
MATCH (to:Person {name: line.TO})
MATCH (from:Person {name: line.FROM})
MERGE (to)-[:FRIEND]->(from)
```

Comment: Thanks @Luanne. It worked for me and gave me a nice head start. I was able to create new nodes, relationships among the present nodes. I also deleted nodes.
 
1) I am curious that is there any way of renaming a person rather than deleting that person and creating new with the desired name. I don't want to delete and create since all the relationships also need to be fixed accordingly later. 

2) How to delete a specific friendship relationship between two nodes?

I really appreciate the help provided. It was my first question on StackOverflow and you helped a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. To rename a person, MATCH (p:Person {id: 1}) SET p.name="new name"
I highly recommend the neo4j docs: https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/ to get you started